# How can I place ships inside a 2D Array (Battleship) (TOP)

Tags: javascript

I'm beginning the project by creating a Ship factory function.

```
// Begin your app by creating the Ship factory function

const Ship = (length, timesHit, currentlySunk) => {
  const hit = () => {
    timesHit++;
  };
  const isSunk = () => {
    if (length === timesHit) {
      currentlySunk = true;
    }
  };
  return { length, timesHit, currentlySunk, hit, isSunk };
};
```

I can then create multiple ship objects and specify their length and determine when they get sunk after their hit counter reaches their total length.

```
let playerShip1 = Ship(3, 0, false); // length = 3, 0 times hit, not sunk
```

Where I'm struggling with is creating coordinates, placing my ship and I can't wrap my head around creating a Gameboard factory and using it to call the Ship factory.

```
// Create Gameboard factory.
// Gameboards should be able to place ships at specific coordinates by calling the ship factory function.
```

I was able to create a 2D Array to create a 10x10 board where each table is set to null.

```
const Gameboard = () => {
  const rows = 10;
  const columns = 10;
  
  const coords = [];
  const placeCords = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      coords[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        coords[i][j] = null;
      }
    }
  };
};
```

But after that I'm completely lost and I can't figure out how to tie all this together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row and column indexes for your Gameboard are the coordinates you will use, starting at 0 and going up to 9.

In order to place a ship, you will need to specify length (as you have already done), as well as position and direction. You can then use the position as the starting point for your ship, and direction to know which way to fill. In doing so, you will replace the null value at a given index `coords[x][y]` with some value to indicate there is a ship there.

Finally, you will need a method to create the ships. You can do this either by user input, or by just using hardcoded values in the Gameboard creator function. You will also need to store all your ships in a list, and have a way to call upon the correct ship when a shot hits.